# Linq Evaluate Nullable types in select clause

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I get a weird exception: `"Unknown Expression type: IIF(e.Accredited.Value, 1, 0)"`
running the following statement:

```
var x = from e in _EntityManager.TrainingCourses
            select new { Disabled = (e.Accredited.Value ? 1 : 0) };
```

Please help!! How do I evaluate a (bool?) in the select

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does this code answer your question? Checking for the bool value explicitly seems to do the trick:

```
void Main()
{

    var a = new List<acc>() { 
        new acc(){Accredited = false}, 
        new acc(){Accredited = true}, 
        new acc(){Accredited = null}
        };

    var x = from e in a
        select new { Disabled = (e.Accredited == true ? 1 : 0) };

    foreach (var i in x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
public struct acc
    {
       public bool? Accredited;
    }
```

Output:
0
1
0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `e.Accredited` is a `Nullable<bool>` (`bool?`), try this:

```
var x = from e in _EntityManager.TrainingCourses
        select new { Disabled = (e.Accredited.HasValue && e.Accredited.Value) };
```

Comment: this does work, but Disabled must be set to 1 or 0 not true or false. what it I have to return "Is disabled" or  "is not disabled". I want to know how to use the ? : statement in a linq select clause